# Select drop down in Android Webview version 50.+ not functional

Tags: android, html, jquery-mobile, drop-down-menu, webview

We're facing a new and peculiar problem when using a simple Select drop down in a hybrid app in Android Webview after the latest update (50.0.+).

Behavior of the select drop down: Blinks twice and opens the Android options list. Upon selecting an item, it doesn't show that item selected - No change in the displayed list.

When we downgrade the Android System Webview to factory settings (v46 or v37), the select box seems to work just fine.

Is anyone else having issues with similar html components and current Android Webview??

We do use JQuery Mobile v 1.4.5 in our app.
And yes, javascript is enabled on the webview.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the problem is different devices have diffenent Android versions and Webview versions.

There is a PROBLEM on webview version 50,51,52, that when I use Webview.loadUrl, it won't work until I touch the Webview once or Twice.

And then, I replace Webview.loadUrl to Webview.evaluateJavascript hoping to solve the problem, but it didn't work neither.

After I upgraded my Webview version to 53 through Google Play, the Problem was solved. But it doesn't make sense.

CrossWalk Engine will add about 20MB to the APK size, so it won't be my first choice.